# Prawn PDF Image Comes With Text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I am using prawn pdf in Rails 3.
I try to embed an image into my pdf file using

```
image "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/logo.png", :height => 30
```

The resulting PDF consists of the logo, which is good. However there is this line:

```
#<Prawn::Images::PNG:0x007ff7d1438f20>
```

printed below the logo.

There is nothing special with my code, I am just following this Railscast to set things up:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn
and added the image code.

May I ask if anyone faces the same problem and how to resolve it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Images.html

Comment: What version of Prawn?

Comment: Ah I have found the answer. image returns the data of the file too. Thanks Louis for pointing me out and let me re-read that documentation again.